# Angular 2 Rxjs : Apply distinct on objects

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have obeservables of these objects :

```
  {
        id : "f3055770-6e66-4936-8e9a-732b53121549"
        message:"Empty Notification for test ......"
        navigationLink:"/fusion/home"
        seen:false 
        sendedOn:"2016-12-02T15:19:44.856Z"
        userId :null
      }
```

I would like to not receive duplicated object (based on ids) and i use this method to achieve it

```
 notify(userID: string) {
    return Observable.interval(5000)
        .map(() => this.baseUrl + '/notification/GetUnseen?userId=' + userID)
        .switchMap(url => {
            return Observable.from(this.datatService.get(url));
        })
        .flatMap(response => Observable.from(response.json().slice()))

}
```

When i add distinct(x => x.id) as last operator i have only one object instead of Four any help ?

**UPDATE :**

I call this method in the oninit() life cycle of my component, so that the method execute every 5 second to get notification, i use distict this way :

```
 notify(userID: string) {
    return Observable.interval(5000)
        .map(() => this.baseUrl + '/notification/GetUnseen?userId=' + userID)
        .switchMap(url => {
            return Observable.from(this.datatService.get(url));
        })
        .flatMap(response => Observable.from(response.json().slice()))
        .distinct(x => x.id);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Serveur raw response :

```
"[{"userId":null,"sendedOn":"2016-12-02T15:19:44.856Z","message":"Empty Notification for test ......","navigationLink":"/fusion/home","seen":false,"id":"f3055770-6e66-4936-8e9a-732b53121549"},{"userId":null,"sendedOn":"2016-12-02T15:19:45.146Z","message":"Empty Notification for test ......","navigationLink":"/fusion/home","seen":false,"id":"ce172122-11d9-4054-a3e4-594c8c910a7d"},{"userId":null,"sendedOn":"2016-12-02T15:19:45.146Z","message":"Empty Notification for test ......","navigationLink":"/fusion/home","seen":false,"id":"66e32c45-f544-4ce6-901c-e5ac64904954"},{"userId":null,"sendedOn":"2016-12-02T15:19:45.147Z","message":"Empty Notification for test ......","navigationLink":"/fusion/home","seen":false,"id":"4c2322cb-526c-490e-8a86-f1e9ced1c34f"}]"
```

Comment: Can you please give the context: 1) How do you call this method? 2) Where do you add the `distinct` operator?

Comment: Are you sure those four objects don't have the same `id`?

Comment: Updated, @martin yeah am shure that the ids are not the same

Comment: @NacimIdjakirene Can you show the raw response from server before you pass it to `.json()`?

Comment: See the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for the distinct !

In fact, the function passed to disctinct can take 2 parameters (precedentValue, actualValue) so you can resolve this issue like this :

```
....
....
.distinct(function (x, y) { return x.id === y.id; });
```

It return a boolean on each iteration (is x.id = y.id ? => true or false...).

**UPDATE **

My mistake is that i was looking for the rxjs 4.0 documentation, and my project is on rxjs 5 .